# How to implement notification service in web app deployed on aws?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, serverless

I am building web apps which is using React and AWS Lambda deployed on AWS.
But I should implement notification service in web app. As you know we can't use WebSockets or socket.io on serverless so I looked around the idea of how to implement it. I just found about aws sns and IoT to implement notification service. But is there any other way to implement this? We should send notifications to the special people also. If you have any idea, please share with me. Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with using SNS? You can send notifications using email or SMS using it to those "special people".

Comment: email or sms is okay. But we should show the notification on the web app also. Like the facebook notification.

Comment: Please improve the structure of your question. Don't write one single paragraph of text.